# Cloudflare customer certificate in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloudflare

I am working on automating generation of Cloudflare client certificate and upload to AWS acm using terraform. But I can't seem to find Cloudflare resource for client certificate generation. I believe I went through all resources with "cert" in it's name. Perhaps someone can share some documentation or examples on how to generate client certificate using terraform?

Comment: There is a TLS provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs. But why would you want to create a Cloudflare cert and upload it to ACM when you can generate ACM certificates?

Comment: @MarkoE I'm not fully sure. I know that this approach will only be used for dev environment.

Comment: @MarkoE regarding ACM, is there a simple way to do it in terraform? As I understand I would need to create cert request, get CNAME values and create record in cloudflare?

Comment: Yeah, those are probably the steps you would need to take.